# Why is this numba.cuda lookup table implementation failing?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm trying to implement an transform which at some stage in it has a lookup table < 1K in size. This seems to me like it shouldn't pose a problem to a modern graphics card.

But the code below is failing with an unknown error:

```
from numba import cuda, vectorize
import numpy as np

tmp = np.random.uniform( 0, 100, 1000000 ).astype(np.int16)
tmp_device = cuda.to_device( tmp )

lut = np.arange(100).astype(np.float32) * 2.5
lut_device = cuda.to_device(lut)

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def lookup(x):
    return lut[x]

@vectorize("float32(int16)", target="cuda")
def test_lookup(x):
    return lookup(x)

test_lookup(tmp_device).copy_to_host() # <-- fails with cuMemAlloc returning UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR
```

What am I doing against the spirit of numba.cuda?

Even replacing `lookup` with the following simplified code results in the same error:

```
@cuda.jit(device=True)
def lookup(x):
    return x + lut[1]
```

Once this error occurs, I am essentially no longer able to utilize the cuda context at all. For instance, allocating a new array via `cuda.to_device` results in a:

```
numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver.CudaAPIError: [719] Call to cuMemAlloc results in UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR
```

---

Running on: 4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04)

Driver Version: 390.25

numba: 0.33.0

Comment: I would guess the numba compiler is producing broken code for the 16 bit integer to float conversion internally. Check the code of the generated compiled functions

Comment: @talonmies: what makes you think that? I've just tested and the above code also fails if I use int32 instead.

Comment: What makes me think that is that UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR is usually generated when a kernel executes an invalid instruction or performs an out of bounds memory access resulting in a hardware exception that kills your context. My next suggestion would be to pass LUT as an argument to the functions rather than assume it is global scope. That might break things

Comment: Thanks for the hint with regards to invalid instruction. With regards to passing the LUT as an argument: I've thought of that, but I honestly don't know how I could semantically pass a lookup table to a vectorized function + a kernel without it being incorrectly interpreted.

Comment: The decorator syntax shows you to show the computer that an argument is an array not a scalar

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting something that simply works... however, before I bang my head further on this problem: is there anything inherently not doable about maintaining and using a lookup table in gpu memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is fixed by modifying the part in bold:

```
@cuda.jit(device=True)
def lookup(x):
    lut_device = cuda.const.array_like(lut)
    return lut_device[x]
```

I ran multiple variations of the code including simply touching the lookup table from within this kernel, but not using its output. This combined with @talonmies' assertion that UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR usually occurs with invalid instructions, I thought that perhaps there was a shared memory constraint that was causing the issue.

The above code makes the whole thing work. However, I still don't understand why in a *profound* way.

If anyone knows and understands why, please feel free to contribute to this answer.